# Which textbox events should use

Tags: c#

I have 2 text boxes in a form. One is the `total` which has addition of all product list and another is the `tax`. Now what I want to do is to enter some amount to `tax`, which should calculate and set to `total` right away. Please Help me to solve it.

Thank You...in Advance..

Comment: [Control.LostFocus Event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.lostfocus%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)?

Comment: Depends. Does the calculation take time and can make the UI freeze for like 0.5 secs then go with `LostFocus`. If it is really very fast, `TextChanged`

Comment: @x... text changed would calculate with every character entered.  Probably not what the OP wants.  Use `Validated` instead.

Comment: use TextChanged event

Comment: @Zambre -- is this WinForms?  WPF?

Comment: for  winform you can use TextChanged

Comment: @HiteshThakor -- Don't keep repeating yourself...what's the point?  You already said it once.  Also, see my comment.  TextChanged is probably not what the OP really wants.

Answer (score 2):

You probably want the `Validated` event, not the `TextChanged` event.  If you use `TextChanged`, the event will fire after every character that is typed, which is probably not what you want.  Most likely, you want it to fire only when the user is finished entering the value and leaves the text box, which is what the `Validated` event is for.

Note, `LostFocus` will also work, but the `Validated` event is designed for this purpose, because you can combine it with `Validating` and cancel it if the user entered an invalid value, in which case `Validated` will never fire, but `LostFocus` still will.

Answer (score -1):

Sounds like you want to need to create a delegate method that handles the text changed event.

In your constructor / init:

```
TextBox1_TextChanged += FunctionToHandle;
```

Inside this text changed event, you should validate first that you are getting an actual number, once that is done you simply do your calculation and add it to the property that is bound to your total textbox.

Comment: Text changed would calculate with every character entered. Probably not what the OP wants.

Comment: that's why i said validate first.

Comment: The TextChanged event will fire *before* Validating.  If you use TextChanged, it will **fire every time a character is typed**.  Even if your delegate "validates" (which is not the right place to do it), the event will still fire again on the next char that is typed.  AND, the *validated* event will STILL fire at the end.  There's no way to cancel it other than to use the *validating* event.

Comment: If nothing handles the validated event, it doesn't matter if it fires a million times. we wont see it....

Comment: Okay, so just do things the wrong way rather than the way that's built for this purpose?  That's your answer?  How do you answer the fact that every character that is typed will fire the event?  What user would not find that annoying?

Comment: lol have you used google lately? an event firing after every keystroke is preferred as you can do instant search....